# checking class of R-DBI connection object

Tags: r, odbc, r-dbi

I'm [rewriting a function](https://github.com/OuhscBbmc/REDCapR/blob/f34f8a54384631cce4fb5baf4f319142eaed8ff9/R/retrieve-credential.R#L154-L155) that optionally accepts a connection object.  The parameter should be verified that it's a valid connection/channel.  How do I do this robustly with the [`DBI`](https://db.rstudio.com/dbi/) package?  (Specifically, I'm using [`odbc`](https://db.rstudio.com/odbc/) package.)

I'd like something that accommodates all [DBI](https://github.com/r-dbi/DBI) connection objects, but I'll settle for just odbc connection objects

Running something like this doesn't produce a value I know how to query with [`inherits()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.0/topics/class).

```
library(DBI)
con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")
class(con)
# [1] "SQLiteConnection"
# attr(,"package")
# [1] "RSQLite"
DBI::dbDisconnect(con)
```

In contrast, the [RODBC](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=RODBC)  and [pool](https://github.com/rstudio/pool) return a class than I can grab better (*ie*, `RODBC` and `Pool`) .

If it helps, here are more internals from this particular DBI connection.

```
> str(con)
Formal class 'SQLiteConnection' [package "RSQLite"] with 7 slots
  ..@ ptr                :<externalptr> 
  ..@ dbname             : chr ":memory:"
  ..@ loadable.extensions: logi TRUE
  ..@ flags              : int 70
  ..@ vfs                : chr ""
  ..@ ref                :<environment: 0x0000000000000000> 
  ..@ bigint             : chr "integer64"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DBI spec requires¹ all connections to inherit from `DBIConnection`. The "new style" backends all implement it like this, IIRC:

```r
library(RSQLite)
con <- dbConnect(SQLite())
inherits(con, "DBIConnection")
#> [1] TRUE
```

> Created on 2018-05-18 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

---

¹ scratch "requires": eventually will require explicitly, https://github.com/r-dbi/DBItest/issues/170

Comment: Cool.  I didn't realize `inherits()` would detect values that weren't produced by `class()`.  When I inspect an object, is there a function that lists the values that `inherits()` would detect?

Comment: This is S4. You need `extends(RSQLite:::.__C__SQLiteConnection)` and probably also `is()` is slightly better than `inherits()`.